# How to create a polldaddy like editor

Tags: asp.net, ajax, panels

Most of you here must have used polldaddy. I would like to get some advise from you guys about how can I design an editor like the one seen in polldaddy. Below is a screenshot.

On the left side there is a list of controls (Text box, list etc) and on the right there is a panel(editor). I can click and drag on of the control and as soon as I drop it in the panel it aligns itself int he panel and shows other options. How can I do this using asp.net? Any samples or ideas would be great.

Thanks

[alt text http://hdwall1.googlepages.com/poll.JPG](http://hdwall1.googlepages.com/poll.JPG)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have a lot of work to do.

Ignoring your server side model, you cashould probably use jQuery/jQuery UI/ExtJS or any other UI framework to allow drag/drop sort functionality.

I am not familiar with PollDaddy but I imagine that there's a lot of code there to achieve a poll/form builder. You could look at their code too assuming its not packed.

hope this helps.